# Regex to remove duplicated characters and combinations

Tags: python, regex, string, duplicates

I have a string that consists of words that have duplicated characters at the end of it.
These characters may be in such combinations:

- **wordxxxx**
- **wordxyxyxy**
- **wordxyzxyzxyz**

For example:

string = **"Thisssssssss isisisis echooooooo stringggg. Replaceaceaceace repeatedededed groupssss of symbolssss"**

I've found a way to replace some of the repeated combinations, this way:

`re.sub(r'([a-z]{1,3})\1+', r'\1', string)`

I'm getting these results:

**Thisss is echoooo stringg. Replace repeated groupss of symbolss**

How should I change the regex to remove ALL the repeated characters and their combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct.

- You need to add `?` to the capturing group, so it matches as little as it can ("lazy matching" rather than the default "greedy" behavior that matches as much as possible).
- I also used `+` instead of `{1,3}` because limiting the repetition to `3` seemed arbitrary.
- You can observe the difference between the two behaviors: [greedy](https://regex101.com/r/eHHABG/1) vs [lazy](https://regex101.com/r/bhGhKl/1).
  Note that:

  1. The greedy behavior sees `aaaa` as `aa * 2` rather than `a * 4`
  2. The greedy behavior only works for even-lengthed repetitions. `aaaaa` is seen as

     `aa * 2 + a` thus the replacement result would be `aaa` instead of `a`.

```
for word in "Thisssssssss isisisis echooooooo stringggg. Replaceaceaceace repeatedededed groupssss of symbolssss".split():
    print(re.sub(r'([a-z]+?)\1+', r'\1', word))
```

outputs

```
This
is
echo
string.
Replace
repeated
groups
of
symbols
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning here exactly what is going wrong when using the greedy quantifier, namely that "ssss" is being analysed as "ss" * 2 rather than "s" * 4.

Comment: @alaniwi Thanks, I added that explanation + an interesting insight about odd-lengthed repetitions.

Answer (score -1):

One Liner Solution

```
string = "Thisssssssss isisisis echooooooo stringggg. Replaceaceaceace repeatedededed groupssss of symbolssss"
print(re.sub(r'([a-z]+?)\1+', r'\1', string))
#This is echo string. Replace repeated groups of symbols
```